# Como pegar um valor dentro do array

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Gostaria de saber como fazer para pegar o valor desse array

```
Array ( [TIMEDIFF('2017-12-14 17:44:14', '2017-12-14 16:12:21')] => 01:31:53 )
```

Já tentei

```
$timEnd  = $resultConvertido['TIMEDIFF('2017-12-14 17:44:14', '2017-12-14 16:12:21')'];
```

porém retorna isso:

```
Notice: Undefined index: [TIMEDIFF('2017-12-14 17:44:14', '2017-12-14 16:12:21')] in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\getTime.php on line 45
```

Comment: Da um `var_dump` em ` $resultConvertido` e coloca o resultado na resposta

Comment: array(1) { ["TIMEDIFF('2017-12-14 17:53:56', '2017-12-14 16:12:21')"]=> string(8) "01:41:35" }

Comment: Já tentou `reset($resultConvertido);` ?

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.